# Баг в bootstrap при использовании модальных окон, созданных программно

Tags: bootstrap

Пробую создавать модальные окна (разметку) в bootstrap программно и отображать потом по нужному событию.

```js
$('#add_app_form').click(function() {
  _alert('test', 'Ошибка');
  return false;
})

var _alertWindow;

function _alert(str, title) {
  if (!_alertWindow) {
    _alertWindow = $('<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">\
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">\
    <div class="modal-content">\
      <div class="modal-header">\
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>\
        <h4 class="modal-title" date-title="Информация">Информация</h4>\
      </div>\
      <div class="modal-body">\
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>\
      </div>\
      <div class="modal-footer">\
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">ОК</button>\
      </div>\
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->\
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->\
</div><!-- /.modal -->')
      .appendTo(document.body);
  }
  _alertWindow.modal();
}
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="add_app_form">тест</a>
```

Окно отображается нормально, но закрывается глючно. При таком создании bootstrap почему-то создает два "окна" затенения $('.modal-backdrop') под модальным окном (разметка, когда отображается модальное окно).

```html
<div class="modal fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="display: block; padding-right: 16px;">...</div><!-- /.modal -->
<div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>
<div class="modal-backdrop in"></div>
```

Сами эти два окна при наложении уменьшают прозрачность, но основная проблема не этом. При закрытии окна bootstrap удаляет только одно окно затенения.
Разметка после закрытия модального окна.

```html
<div class="modal fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="display: block; padding-right: 16px;">...</div><!-- /.modal -->
<div class="modal-backdrop in"></div>
```

Т.к. одно окно .modal-backdrop не удалилось, оно блокирует всю страницу и "затеняет" ее.
Я придумал костыль против этого, но мне он не нравится. Повешать обработку на события закрытия окна и удалять вручную лишнее окно.

```js
_alertWindow.on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
  _alertWindow.find('~ .modal-backdrop.in:last-child').remove();
});
```

Этот костыль не исправляет ошибку с наложением двух окон и непонятно, что будет с несколькими модальными окнами на странице.
Если разметку модального окна сделать в html, никаких глюком не наблюдается.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким глюком и как его избегали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не баг в `bootstrap`, а всего лишь ваша невнимательность.

Посмотрите, что у хранится в переменной `_alertWindow`:

[image: Скриншот окна f12]

Как видите в ней хранится массив из 2 элементов и вторым является комментарий, который идет в конце `html` разметки.

Удалите комментарий или назначьте вашему окну `id` и используйте `$('id').modal();`